JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'org': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
I am using Spring Cloud Stream and spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, version 3.2.10.
I created and configured a custom error handler: spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer1-in-0.error-handler-definition=myErrorHandler
    @Bean
    public Consumer<ErrorMessage> myErrorHandler() {
        return errorMessage -> {
            System.out.println("Handle error...");
        };
    }

When "consumer1" processes a payload (XML String), it simply throws a RuntimeException:
    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> consumer1() {
        return msg-> {
            throw new RuntimeException("Test Error Handling");
        };
    }

When myErrorHandler runs, a WARN and its stacktrace are shown in the log:
2024-09-17 17:38:17,613 [KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='testTopic', partitions=4, dlqName='null'}.container-0-C-1] WARN  org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.SmartCompositeMessageConverter- Failure during type conversion by org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter@d6450a6. Will try the next converter.
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'org': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@3d1b0ed0]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Error Handling, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[24595], headers={deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, scst_partition=0, kafka_receivedTopic=testTopic, target-protocol=kafka, kafka_offset=29, partitionKey=p0, scst_nativeHeadersPr"[truncated 214 chars]; line: 1, column: 4]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'org': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@3d1b0ed0]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Error Handling, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[24595], headers={deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, scst_partition=0, kafka_receivedTopic=testTopic, target-protocol=kafka, kafka_offset=29, partitionKey=p0, scst_nativeHeadersPr"[truncated 214 chars]; line: 1, column: 4]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:237)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.convertFromInternal(ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:185)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.SmartCompositeMessageConverter.fromMessage(SmartCompositeMessageConverter.java:63)


Handle error...
Anyone knows how to fix above WARN?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I am not quite sure what are you asking? Fix the WARN?? You can just manage it with your standard logging configuration which has nothing to do with Spring.

@OlegZhurakousky you are right that I could hide that big WARN from log by using error level for this class: org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.SmartCompositeMessageConverter.  But I want to know the correct way to fix it. For me, it seems Spring Cloud Stream + Kafka binder cannot handle such case described in my original question. It tries to use SmartCompositeMessageConverter to convert an xml string (which is NOT Json string)
